# Is there another way to call a local function by an innerHTML button's onclick instead of bind to window?

Tags: javascript, html, closures

Create a button by js and insert to body as a modal, the button's `onclick` handler is a resolve function in promise scope.

When I don't add the resolve to window: `window.resolveAlert = resolve`, the `onclick` will throw an error of not found.

Is there another way to avoid binding the resolve function to `window` to call a scoped function?

```
function showRatingAlert() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const content = `
      <div id="rating-alert">
        <button onclick="resolve(true)">
          Sure
        </button>
      </div>
    `
    window.resolve = resolve // TODO: bad
    const tag = document.createElement('div')
    tag.innerHTML = content
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(tag)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attach the event listener properly using Javascript instead - use `addEventListener`, and then you can just pass the `resolve` variable to it:

```js
function showRatingAlert() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const content = `
      <div id="rating-alert">
        <button>
          Sure
        </button>
      </div>
    `;
    const tag = document.createElement('div');
    tag.innerHTML = content;
    // tag.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', resolve);
    // you can ensure the listener only runs once by passing { once: true }, if you wish:
    tag.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', resolve, { once: true });
    document.body.appendChild(tag);
  })
}

showRatingAlert()
  .then(() => console.log('resolved'));
```

Inline handlers should almost always be avoided - they require global pollution to work and don't have the benefit of the scope of the closure in which the listener is attached (as you can see).